# Convert NSString with format Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:22:04 EDT to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert the `NSString` with following format:
`Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:22:04 EDT` to `NSDate`
but I am always getting `nil`.

Here's my attempt

```
// This is my pub date in string** 

NSString *pubDate = @"Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:22:04 EDT";

NSArray *tempArr =[ pubDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *tempArrFinal = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArr];
[tempArrFinal removeLastObject];
[tempArrFinal removeObjectAtIndex:0];
pubDate = [tempArrFinal componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Here before passing it to date formatter I converted the `NSString` to format which is like this: `27 Aug 2013 22:22:04` by removing first n last component of the string. I've done this because with its original format i am getting same result.

This is how i am trying o convert it to `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

articleDate = [formatter dateFromString:pubDate];
```

Comment: Try  [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

Answer (score 2):

You have to set NSDateFormatter according to your date format

try this, if you using this type of date `27 Aug 2013 22:22:04`

```
NSString *string=@"27 Aug 2013 22:22:04";
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:string];
```

**OR**
if you using `Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:22:04 EDT` this type of date 
try this

```
NSString *string=@"Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:22:04 EDT";
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zz"];
NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:string];
```